# Is there a way to get last accessed timestamp for items within a site collection including list items, pages, library, documents and sub sites?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

My SharePoint site collection quota is about to reach and I need to clean up so I want to delete items (including lists, items, pages, libraries, subsites etc.)  which has not been accessed in the last 6 months. Is there a way to get this report?

Usage reports display the number of hits and not the pages.

Note: Auditing feature was not enabled.

Comment: No, as the crawler account access all the content when it's being crawled. One thing you should be able to do is to see if any subsite could be exported to it's own site collection.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using

```
https://<yoursite>.sharepoint.com/_api/web?$select=LastItemModifiedDate
```

This might not be the most indicative way to tell if a site is being used but should at least get you going on your way.